# Define externalized groovy file in test step definition

Tags: soapui

I'd like to externalize my groovy scripts to a file. Instead of

```
<con:testStep type="groovy" name="Init" id="ba3d9999-6cf7-4697-ac71-2472a61f16fc">
    <con:settings/>
    <con:config>
        <script>log.info "[ isr::CallbackController::Init ] "</script>
    </con:config>
</con:testStep>
```

I'd prefer something like this:

```
<con:testStep type="groovy" name="Init" id="ba3d9999-6cf7-4697-ac71-2472a61f16fc">
    <con:settings/>
    <con:config>
        <script file="path/to/my.groovy"/>
    </con:config>
</con:testStep>
```

Comment: Do you know if that is supported by soapUI?

Comment: @Rao I think that currently is not possible, since the `script` is a property in *groovy script TestStep* which contains directly the script, and looking at the custom properties I don't see nothing which can support this.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is not currently supported in SOAPUI, maybe you can add a feature request to it :).

However in the meantime maybe the following tricky workaround could be useful for you.

I purpose you to create a groovy script testStep which reads your script from a file, dynamically create a groovy testStep, sets the script with the file content, execute this new dynamic created testStep and finally remove it in order that it can be run it multiple times. See the follow script:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.GroovyScriptStepFactory

// read the file with your script
File f = new File('path/to/my.groovy')

def tc = testRunner.testCase
// create a empty groovy testStep in the current testCase
def groovyTS = tc.addTestStep( GroovyScriptStepFactory.GROOVY_TYPE, "Groovy testStep dinamic" )

// set the file script as a content
groovyTS.properties["script"].value = f.text

// run the the created testStep with your script
groovyTS.run(testRunner,context)

// once runned delete it
tc.removeTestStep(groovyTS)
```

As @Rao note in the comments, maybe an easy way to do so it's simply use `evaluate` in the *groovy script testStep* as:

```
evaluate(new File('path/to/my.groovy'))
```

At first I avoid this option thinking on possible problems with context variables like `testRunner`, `context`, `log`... and I use the option to create *groovy testStep* to keep it as similar as possible to the SOAPUI way. However using `evaluate` seems a really nice and easier workaround.

Comment: That's wonderful workaround. Nice to see you after long wait. Evaluate is also another option?

Comment: Thanks for your kind words :), I was around this days... but not answering for a long. You're totally right, `evaluate` it's a good option, at first I avoid it because I thought could be some problems with context variables like `testRunner`, `context`... but seems that they working correctly, so as usual thanks for the tip!

Comment: Always I have a feeling that more % of the questions are answered if you would have been more active. Once again you have shown the sportsmanship in taking the comments. Not only me, but the community missed you these days and hoping that the wait is over.